# Artifactory : Fresh install add LDAP settings failed

Tags: artifactory

Trying to add LDAP settings to freshly installed Artifactory v7.41.13.

After fresh install (Docker or Debian package)

`systemctl start artifactory` or `docker run --name artifactory-oss -v $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest`

Im trying to add LDAP settings in the UI and got the "Oops, something went wrong" error

LDAP settings work in our production Artifactory on the same version. I tried even with a Pro version.

I got this error only with valid manager password, if I input the wrong password, everything (but LDAP connection) works.

Log output

```
2022-10-07T13:14:01.627Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [4cde5ae479529aa2] [c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:922] [http-nio-8081-exec-2] - Reloading configuration... old revision 0, new revision 1
2022-10-07T13:14:01.703Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [4cde5ae479529aa2] [c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:961] [http-nio-8081-exec-2] - Failed to reload configuration: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
2022-10-07T13:14:01.708Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [4cde5ae479529aa2] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:190      ] [http-nio-8081-exec-2] - Last retry failed: Failed to reload configuration: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.. Not trying again
2022-10-07T13:14:01.722Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [4cde5ae479529aa2] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:48] [http-nio-8081-exec-2] - Could not merge and save new descriptor [org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: Failed to reload configuration: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.. Not trying again]
```

Could you please give me a hint what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Artifactory is unable to decrypt the password being provided as the manager password. Are you trying to use the LDAP manager credentials as same as in your PROD environment? If yes, I believe that you trying to use a manager password that's encrypted. Please try with a plain-text password.

Because, these errors would occur if the master.key used for decrypting the password is different from the one that's encrypting it.

Comment: You are right, thank you! But tell me, why Artifactory tries to decrypt it? What if this string would be my real plain text password?